# How to use subfolders with Github Actions and Monorepo?

Tags: github-actions

It has a monorepo, where it will contain two subfolders, which are:

[image: folders]

Each with their respective projects and packages. I am trying to access a certain subfolder to do its respective action, but it is giving an error when I run a command to test with lint, which is:

```
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/github/workspace"
```

**It probably should not be accessing the frontend subfolder. I need it to run all the commands in this subfolder, how do I do it?**

**MY `.YML`:**

```
name: PIPELINE OF TESTS

on:
  push:
    branches: [frontend-develop, backend-develop]
  pull_request_target:
    types: [opened, edited, closed]
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  test-frontend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./frontend
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        architecture: [x64]
    steps:
      - name: CHECK-OUT GIT REPOSITORY
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: USE NODEJS ${{ matrix.node-version }} - ${{ matrix.architecture }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2

      - name: INSTALL PROJECT DEPENDENCIES (YARN)
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: install

      - name: CODE ANALYSE (LINT) AND STYLE-GUIDE ANALYSE (PRETTIER + AIRBNB)
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: lint-check

      - name: UNIT TEST (JEST)
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: test
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `defaults` with `run` will only be applied to the run step (e.g scripts/commands that you execute yourself and **not** actions). See the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iddefaultsrun):

> Provide default `shell` and `working-directory` to all `run` steps in the
> job. Context and expression are not allowed in this section.

When you are using a GitHub action (you have `uses:`) it not possible to change the working directory. Keep in mind that some actions support this - you can pass an additional argument to `with:`, but in your case `borales/actions-yarn` do not support that.

What can you do?

As suggested in the `borales/actions-yarn` [REAME.md](https://github.com/borales/actions-yarn):

> **Please keep in mind** that this Action was originally written for GitHub Actions beta (when Docker was the only way of doing things).
> Consider using [actions/setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) to work with Yarn. This repository will be mostly supporting the existing flows.

You can remove these actions and call yarn directly in `run:`. Your workflow should look like:

```
name: PIPELINE OF TESTS

on:
  push:
    branches: [frontend-develop, backend-develop]
  pull_request_target:
    types: [opened, edited, closed]
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  test-frontend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./frontend
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        architecture: [x64]
    steps:
      - name: CHECK-OUT GIT REPOSITORY
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: USE NODEJS ${{ matrix.node-version }} - ${{ matrix.architecture }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2

      - name: INSTALL PROJECT DEPENDENCIES (YARN)
        run: yarn install

      - name: CODE ANALYSE (LINT) AND STYLE-GUIDE ANALYSE (PRETTIER + AIRBNB)
        run: yarn lint-check

      - name: UNIT TEST (JEST)
        run: yarn test
```

Comment: I just stumbled into this and was able to do this with actions/setup-node@v2 by setting cache-dependency-path https://naomiaro.hashnode.dev/nodejs-ci-github-action